# Is it possible to gain a shell on this?

Tags: pcb, uart

In my want for discovering cool things, i want to try and gain a shell on this potato-chip.

Spec sheet: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm8s103f2.pdf

[image: this is from a printer]

I think it is possible from reading the documentation. I believe to connect the pins pd4 pd5 pd6 plus one other to my uart serial device.

I think the one other is ground (pin VSS).

Do i still also have to power the chip aswell?
Such as pin VDD?

Comment: I know you're trying to be funny, but "shell" and"potato chip" really don't help me to understand what you're trying to do. What do you think a "shell" is? And yes, you need to power it, have decoupling capacitors, and other components to connect it to a computer.

Comment: What does the expression "gain a shell" mean? I suggest that you use standard electrical engineering terminology if you want an answer.

Comment: "gain a shell"? What does that mean?

Comment: to interact with using a serial device, to edit and alike the firmware on the chip. Damn, in a modern world, cant anyone chill out just a little.

Comment: You're three days late for an April's fools joke.

Comment: @RonBeyer I find little about this funny? Perhaps your funny meter is broken.

Comment: Sure we can chill but how were we supposed to interpret "gain a shell"? New question: what does "*alike the firmware on the chip*" (in your comment above) mean? Ron's comment should give you some clues to the answer.

Comment: Maybe it is, but you are coming for us for help, the least you could do is to call it what it is (a microcontroller), and learn that there is no such thing as "gaining a shell" on one. Microcontrollers don't have shells (in the computer sense). You haven't explained what you are really trying to do, you just said "how can I gain a shell on this potato chip?". Why should I spend my time trying to figure out what on earth you are talking about, and then try to solve your problem? If you said "I'm trying to interface an STM8 to an XYZ via UART, do I need any external components", it would be easy

Comment: evidently i do not know enough about the subject. Surely people with knowledge want to have people start in their field. I'm a developer, but never touched this kind of stuff before. I want to discover new things and learn, but it seems almost like you don't want new learners for your field perhaps? Gain a shell is common knowledge for my field. I respect your field, enough to ask on an already known for its hostile q&a website such as here. 

Thanks for the generic answer of yes it needs power. That was the main question. Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a microcontroller. It has UART interface. It needs power and firmware to do anything. It does have a bootloader so you can download firmware over UART. If you want to interface with a text-based shell or console interface, you need to write firmware that does it yourself. Many devices do implement a serial debugging console because it is convenient way to test and debug a device.